# Java regex to match quoted numbers

Tags: java, regex, json

I need to clean up a JSON including incorrectly quoted numbers via a short Java (not JS!) Regex snippet. Example for what I have:

```
[{"series":"a","x":"1","y":"111.71"},{"series":"a","x":"2","y":"120.25"}]
```

Example for what I would need to get:

```
[{"series":"a","x":1,"y":111.71},{"series":"a","x":2,"y":120.25}]
```

So I only need to match and eliminate quote characters if preceeded or followed by [0-9], but how to avoid replacing part of the number is beyond my lowly regex skills.

Any help greatly appreciated!

EDIT (2nd round):

Thanks for the fast feedback! I'm not too worried about false positives since I can control the contents of the descriptors, and I'll make sure they're text-only. Spaces can be avoided as well, only negative numbers might occur - good one! Separators are always commas (",") for the JSON, the arbitrary number of decimals in of the double values are always separated by dots ("."). I cannot fix the JSON source unfortunately, and I definitely want to clean this up in Java.

Trying out the suggestions now and reporting back. I'll also toy around with this:  http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind

Comment: Can numbers be negative? Have comma `,` separators? spaces?

Comment: *"I only need to match and eliminate quote characters if preceeded or followed by [0-9]..."* It's slightly more complicated than that, or you'll get false positives on things like `"foo": "bar25"`. :-)

Comment: Rather than pre-processing the JSON, could you post-process the deserialized object graph? That might be easier. It's awkward doing this kind of thing with regular expressions because of escaped quotes (although I think Java has the relevant look-ahead feature, so...).

Comment: Do you have access to the source of the JSON? Numbers should not be formatted like strings in JSON, and most Java libs at least handles this just fine. Changing it at the source would be a much more robust solution if possible.

Comment: Thanks to all commenters, this has been most helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about  `replaceAll("\"(-?\\d+([.]\\d+)?)\"","$1");`

Comment: @assylias Your regex will also work correctly so I am not sure if my answer is better :) Also OP didn't answer your comment so `-?` could be overkill :D

Comment: I can see the logic to "-?", as indeed there might be negatives I may want to catch - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This works for your specific example, but would not work if other numbers have a different format (see my comment):

```
String s = "[{\"series\":\"a\",\"x\":\"1\",\"y\":\"111.71\"},{\"series\":\"a\",\"x\":\"2\",\"y\":\"120.25\"}]";
String clean = s.replaceAll("\"(\\d+\\.?\\d*)\"", "$1");
System.out.println(clean);
```

outputs:

```
[{"series":"a","x":1,"y":111.71},{"series":"a","x":2,"y":120.25}]
```

Comment: I was all worried about escaped quotes, but I can't come up with an example of escaped quotes in well-formed JSON that would get impacted by the above. Got to love a scoped problem domain. Nice one. :-)

Comment: This one worked for me, though I didn't try negative double and int values. Thanks! Now trying the Pshemo's as well, and trying to understand both to give an appropriate answer acceptance indication.